# How to get data from an endpoint API in realtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest, api

I would like to get the live results from an Api endpoint preferably using javascript, nodejs. I am looking for more like a technique or idea how to handle this.

Api response looks as following:

```
[
  {
      "id": 6,
      "team1": {
        "name": "Home Team",
        "goals": 2
      },
      "team2": {
        "name": "Away Team",
        "goals": 1
      },
      "starting": "2018-09-14T15:30:00Z"
  }
]
```

Probably one way I can think of doing is making a new request every second and get up to date. So each time a team scores this api changes so I get the latest score goal results.

What is the best way I can handle this without overwhelming the resources of the server or probably not get banned from the API Endpoint if I am doing too many requests.

Comment: Check if the 3rd Party API you are using provides web-hooks, that way, you will aways have fresh data without making unnecessary requests

Comment: @AnandUndavia I dont think they are providing such things, not at least I am aware of. Does that mean there is no other way of achieving a scalable solution?